# Is it possible to detect what app the user currently opened?

Tags: react-native

I am currently building a voice call app using React native and I want to detect what app the user currently have opened, for ex, spotify or instagram since my voice call app is most likely in the background. Is it possible to detect which app the user currently have opened?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to know whether your app is in the background, you can use AppState, which is provided in the React Native core libraries: https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

I'm fairly sure you can't know what app is open, other than your own, on iOS or Android. I hope not, there are considerable security risks.